# Converting date class to string

Tags: c++

I have a Date class

```
class Date { int dd, mm, yyyy};
```

I have written the rule of 3, and all that works. I want to convert the Date into a string. Do I need a conversion operator string() to do so? 
thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I want to make a text representation of an object available, I usually write a (`public`) `print()` method that takes a [`std::ostream&`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/). This makes it easy for me to unit test and it exposes the private data without needing to make `friend`s.

```
void Date::print(std::ostream& s) const
{
    s << yyyy << "-" << mm << "-" << dd;
}
```

This makes writing the stream [insertion operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) that [Jesus Ramos suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135842/convering-date-class-to-string/7135855#7135855) nice and simple:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const Date& d)
{
    d.print(s);
    return s;
}
```

And if you (really) want a `std::string()` `operator`, then that's trivial:

```
Date::operator std::string() const
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    print(oss);
    return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: I don't really recommend making an std::string cast operator because then you will run into compile errors if you have a class with constructors taking `string` and `Date` respectively.

Answer (score 5):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const Date& d)
{
    s << "Format your date object here";
    return s;
}
```

In C++ you use streams if you want toString() like functionality.

So for example you could do

```
s << mm << "/" << dd << "/" << yyyy;
```

Comment: Do you mean `ostream` here?  `std::stream` is new to me.

Comment: Don't forget to return the `std::ostream`!

Comment: @Johnysweb and I just got off finishing some work for today so that explains the braindeadedness (if that's even a word)

Comment: @itcplpl: Then Jesus' should probably be your accepted answer!

Comment: well, both work for me...I can only accept one, that's why I voted up both :-)